# Any JavaScript Modifications Needed for Mozilla?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In need of JavaScript Solution for Exporting table to Excel which works in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050462/in-need-of-javascript-solution-for-exporting-table-to-excel-which-works-in-all-b)

My Requirement is that I want the Table to be exported to Excel by clicking on Button "Export".In my code I have one issue in Exporting HTML table (in JSP Page) to Excel . As of now , it is exporting from Internet explorer but not from mozillaFireFox.  I want to Export it from all Browsers (by clicking on the button) like mozilla firefox, Internet explorer. Can any one help me in this? My java Script as follows.

```
function Export_to_Excel()
{ 
    alert (" Welcome !  Have a Nice Day"); 

    var x=excel.rows;

    var objExcel  = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 

    objExcel.Visible = true; 
    var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; 

    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    { 

        var y=x[i].cells; 

        for(j=0;j<y.length;j++)
        { 
              objWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i+1, j+1).value=y[j].innerText; 
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, no other browser supports ActiveX. From Chrome's FAQ: *"ActiveX is only supported by Internet Explorer (and browsers built on top of Internet Explorer) on Windows. Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Apple Safari, and others do not support ActiveX. Instead, these browsers make use of the Netscape Plugin Application Programming Interface (NPAPI)."* Not sure if you can use it to communicate with Excel. I would think no.

Comment: Any one can tell me the java script without ActiveXobject? (which makes it wrok in both mozilla and IE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ActiveX, Firefox does not support ActiveX.

Comment: Any one can tell me the java script without ActiveXobject? (which makes it wrok in both mozilla and IE)

Comment: You simply cannot. Unless you write a binary reader/writer for XLS files, for which the specifications are not open source. You need server-side technology to achieve what you want, read the comments on your question.

Comment: Thanks cyrille. May i know what Kind of server side technology? How it can be acheived?

Comment: You could for example use PHPExcel: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you very much cyrille for spending your valuable time. I'm working on it.

Comment: You're welcome. Just open another question if you run into problems with PHPExcel or whichever you chose.